# Facebook ads playstore URL

Tags: android, facebook, url, hyperlink, ads

Anyone know about it, i implement facebook ads in my app there is an option of URL of app on google play(can also add later if app not published)

Any one know how to add URL later?
[image]

Check blue marked line , and HELP ME PLEASE

Answer (score 2):

In order to use faceboook ads you must launch the app in google play store. Instead you can try this url

[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%22app) package name"

eg:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana

Comment: You can't understand my question, 
I asked how to add it later means where is the option to add url after my app published on google play. I've URL but where to put it in my property(Given screen shot is of new Property and there is option we can add it later ) i asked how can i add it later where is the option to add URL